# RxJS Loop httpGet result then do httpPut and httpPost on different scenario

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a UI form that to update or add translation text.

I would need to write rxjs statement to fulfill the following:

1. Fire httpGet to database to get translations of multiple languages
2. Loop the list of translations.
3. If my UI fields matches translations from httpGet, I would need to do a series of httpPut to update them in database.
   Example: I filled in Spanish translation in UI, if my httpGet returns results including Spanish, I would need to HttpPut to update Spanish record in database.
4. If my UI fields does not exist in translations from httpGet, I would need to do a series of httpPost to update them in database.
   Example: I filled in Chinese translation in UI, if my httpGet does not return any Chinese result, I would need to httpPost to add Chinese record in database.

I written the first part, but understand that rxjs is not sequential and cannot write a subscribe in another subscribe, I cannot write it in this way.

p/s: My httpGet returns me x, in which has the structure of x.dataCount and x.dataSet. x.dataCount is number of translation object. x.dataSet is an array of translation objects.

How do I write the rxjs statement for this? Any clue?

```
this.GetTranslations(group).subscribe(x => {
  x.dataSet.forEach(translation => {
    switch (translation.Language) {
      case chineseCode:
        if (chineseInUI){
          chineseExist = true;
          let newChinese = {
            "Id": translation.Id,
            "Language": translation.Language,
            "PhraseKey": translation.PhraseKey,
            "PhraseValue": chineseInUI,
          }
          this.webApiService.httpPut$(this.resourceApiService.getURL('translationmanagerURL') + translation.Id, newChinese).subscribe();            }
        break;
      case spanishCode:
        if (spanishInUI){
          let newSpanish = {
            "Id": translation.Id,
            "Language": translation.Language,
            "PhraseKey": translation.PhraseKey,
            "PhraseValue": spanishInUI
          }
          this.webApiService.httpPut$(this.resourceApiService.getURL('translationmanagerURL') + translation.Id, newSpanish).subscribe();
        }
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The code you have will only cover the "put" case so far. I think it would be easier to see what you need to do if instead of starting from `x.dataSet.forEach(`, you start from something like `languagesInUI.forEach(language =>`, then if it's in  `x.dataSet` it's put, if it's not then it's a post

Comment: Yeah. It makes sense. I would need to rewrite the code. But it seems need to use pipe and switchmap, in which do not know how to make a request for every x.dataset returned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this using operators

- `mergeMap` to create an array of observables
- `mergeAll` to get the values of the inner observables in the subscription

```
   this.GetTranslations(group)
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((x) => {
          return x.dataSet.map((translation) => {
            switch (translation.Language) {
              case chineseCode:
                if (chineseInUI) {
                  chineseExist = true;
                  let newChinese = {
                    Id: translation.Id,
                    Language: translation.Language,
                    PhraseKey: translation.PhraseKey,
                    PhraseValue: chineseInUI,
                  };
                  return this.webApiService.httpPut$(
                    this.resourceApiService.getURL('translationmanagerURL') +
                      translation.Id,
                    newChinese
                  );
                }
                break;
              case spanishCode:
                if (spanishInUI) {
                  let newSpanish = {
                    Id: translation.Id,
                    Language: translation.Language,
                    PhraseKey: translation.PhraseKey,
                    PhraseValue: spanishInUI,
                  };
                  return this.webApiService.httpPut$(
                    this.resourceApiService.getURL('translationmanagerURL') +
                      translation.Id,
                    newSpanish
                  );
                }
                break;
            }

            return EMPTY;
          });
        }),
        mergeAll()
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
      });
```

[Working example (with mocked data)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dlmfxv?file=index.ts)